# A reason why this isn't a group?

Tags: group-theory

**Why is the following not a group?**

- The set of all functions from the set {a,b,c} to itself, under composition of functions.

The reason I ask is because if the question asked "is this a subgroup?" I would have probably said yes. So my answer to it feels forceful as I am not really believing what I am saying

Answer attempt: Because it says "all" functions, the function that always takes b to c  - i.e there is no identity. Does it even make sense to say this in the first place? Does it constitute as a function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the function that always takes b to c"?

Comment: I was thinking of it in terms of composition of permutations. I just made up a non existent function that always send b to c.

Comment: It means nothing. b is a constant. You can't "always send b to c".

Comment: the set of bijective functions $\{a,b,c\}  \to \{a,b,c\}$ is a group (with composition as the group operation).  If the function is bijective it has an inverse.  But non-bijective functions won't have valid inverses.

Comment: The set of permutations that sends b to c does exist

Comment: Even though the **set** of permutations that send b to c does exist, "the function that always takes b to c" is, as @KennyLau said, a meaningless expression.

Answer (score 2):

Its identity is the function $f:x \mapsto x$.

However, the function $g : x \mapsto a$ has no inverse.

Answer (score 2):

The function which sends each of $a,b,c$ to $a$ has no inverse, as it is not injective. Thus, the set of all functions does not form a group.